# Cloud Firestore - query to get a specific item from a particular document with id

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Attached is my db structure. How can I get a specific saleOrder item by its id?

[image: db]

Below is my query but it isn't working.
Thank you in advance.

```
const ref = collection(db, 'customers', customerId, 'saleOrders');
const q = query(ref, where('id', '==', saleOrderId));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
```

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance. What isn't working about it?

Note that we can't see the values of your `customerId` and `saleOrderId` variables though, so you might want to try if you can reproduce with simpler hard-coded values. And while you're at it, it'd also help if you show what you did with `querySnapshot`, i.e. may show that it is empty by logging `console.log(querySnapshot.empty)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying

```
collection(db, 'customers', customerId, 'saleOrders');
```

So this is:

- A collection `customers`, which you have
- A document in there for the `customerId`, which I assume you have
- A **subcollection* under there called `saleOrders`, which you **don't** have

You cannot query a nested map field with a query operator like that. Even if you could, it wouldn't accomplish anything - as Firestore client-side SDKs always return the full document, not a subset of its fields.

You have a few options:

- Most logically would be to create an actual `saleOrders` subcollection, store the `ID` in there as a top-level field, and then query that subcollection as you now do.
- Alternatively you can load the full document you have right now, and filter the sale orders in your client-side code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and solutions. I'm a newbie in Firebase and I thought that there would be a way to specify a query condition on a field in an array. I will go ahead with the subcollection option.